# Adding blank columns between two variables in a sas dataset

Tags: sas

I want to add a blank column between two variables in a dataset. The number of observations in each adjacent columns is 26. Hence, I want to insert a column in between these two columns which has 26 blank observation. Currently, my dataset looks like:

```
Variable names:  A B C D
observations:    1 2 3 4
                 5 6 7 8
```

I want to add a column between B and C. The new dataset that I want should be as under:

```
Variable names: A B  C D
Observations:   1 2  3 4
```

Is it possible to add blank columns having specific number of observations using SAS. May I please request help with this issue?

Comment: Can you explain with a more detailed example. For example by COLUMN do you mean a VARIABLE? if so give an example name for the variable that you want to create.  Also the number of observations (or ROWS) in a dataset does not vary by "column". If there are 26 rows in your dataset then all of the columns will have 26 rows.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply Tom. I do mean a variable by blank column. Currently, I have 26 obs and 6 variables. I want to add two new variables to this dataset. However, I want to add one of these new variables between second and third variables of my current dataset and another between fourth and fifth variable of my current dataset. The new variables will be character variables and their names can be anything as these variables would contain blank observations. My situation is similar to adding a blank column between two columns in excel spreadsheet. I hope this clarifies my question.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to read in the old dataset in pieces using multiple SET statements using the `KEEP=` dataset option.  So if your input dataset has variables A,B,C,D in that order you can insert a new variable after B using code like this.

```
data want;
  set have(keep=a -- b);
  length new1 $10 ;
  set have ;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tom. Your code has worked for me. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The SAS documentation on variable lists calls that type of list a "name range list".